# How to run a Python script in Jenkins Pipeline and get the last token?

Tags: python, batch-file, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Here is my code for Jenkins Pipeline:

```
A = bat(script:'c:\\python27\\python.exe D:\\A.py', returnStdout: true).tokenize().last
```

It works really well to run the Python script in Batch and get the last token. But now I also want to display the log of this Python script. So I tried code as below:

```
A = bat(script:'c:\\python27\\python.exe D:\\A.py', returnStdout: true).tokenize()
B = A.last
println A
```

But somehow this Python script will run twice, which is NOT what I want.

Any advice?

Comment: I'm trying to run python script in a pipeline but script doesn't run and I'm using your syntax, any idea what can cause it ?

Answer (score 0):

We have in code solution like (this returns last commit from repository):

```
def scriptToRun = """@echo off
    echo | git ls-remote repository_url.git ${branch}"""
result = bat(returnStdout: true, script: scriptToRun).trim()
```

I can see difference only in "echo" part. May be it'll help?